# Drush make: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:74

Tags: drush, ssl

I'm facing a very strange issue with Drush wget and OpenSSL on my mac book (MacOSX Sierra).

When I launch drush make site.make command (which should theoretically download the all modules) it fails with the following error:

```
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/workbench_og/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:74
```

I tried

```
wget https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/rate/7.x
```

and I got the following message:

```
https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/rate/7.xResolving
updates.drupal.org... 151.101.113.175
Connecting to updates.drupal.org|151.101.113.175|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Same message with flags:

```
wget https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/rate/7.x --no-check-certificate
```

[Here](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4618) I found exactly the problem that I have but, even if reinstalling openssl and upgrading the version (current version is OpenSSL 1.0.2l 25 May 2017) the problem persists.

Did someone has the same kind of issue?
And, in case, how did you handle it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workaround fixed my issue:

In **drush.inc**

```
if ($use_wget) {
  drush_shell_exec("wget --no-check-certificate -q --timeout=30 -O %s %s", $destination_tmp, $url);
} else {
  drush_shell_exec("curl --insecure --tlsv1 --fail -s -L --connect-timeout 30 -o %s %s", $destination_tmp, $url);
}
```

so weird anyway...

Comment: You missed a comma before $destination_tmp in the if block.

Comment: Thanks for your remark sorabh. I have corrected the typo. Anyway I forgot about this thread but I found the reason of the error which was related to OpenSSL and PHP Version (5.4). 
The error fixed itself as soon as I removed entirely the PHP previously installed via Liip package (https://php-osx.liip.ch/) and reinstalling it with brew.

Comment: Could you provide the full path for drush.inc